# When Every Time i restarted my system, my oracle will stop their services.. what is the reason?

Tags: oracle11g

Actually, I'm using oracle 11g enterprise edition so that the connection and functionality is all right but when i restarted my computer and try to connect with database it show "THE NETWORK ADAPTER CANNOT ESTABLISH THE CONNECTION" again i'm start the oracle services this was some time waste for every time 
so can anyone tell how to fix it.

Comment: Are the services OracleServiceXYZ and OracleXYZTNSListener set to Startup Type Automatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows... You can set OracleXETNSListner,OracleServiceXE Startup Type Automatic.

Open task manager>services>find OracleXETNSListner,OracleServiceXE>click right>open services> find OracleXETNSListner,OracleServiceXE> set Startup type Automatic.